# showing a popup in fragment makes the activity not to follow `FLAG_FULLSCREEN`

Tags: android, popup, android-fullscreen

I am using the following code in `onCreate` of my activity to make it hide status bar and  Home , back and menu buttons bar.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

This activity has a fragment in which I need to show a popup. When the pop appears, activity will exit from full screen showing the status bar and home and back buttons. Here is the code for showing the pop up.

```
    LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) rv.findViewById(R.id.popup);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, viewGroup);

    // Creating the PopupWindow
    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(getActivity());
    popup.setContentView(layout);
    popup.setWindowLayoutMode(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.setHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.setFocusable(true);
```

How can I force the FLAG_FULLSCREEN ??

Comment: What about changing theme of the application/ `R.layout.popup_layout`

Comment: What do you get if you call `popup.getWindowLayoutType ()`?

Comment: @Sree I dont require the pop up to be full screen. The Activity which is in Fullscreen mode (Hiding the statusbar ui etc) will no longer be in Fullscreen if popup appear on screen!